# Using double underscore to directly update foreign key's field in Django?

Tags: python, django, double-underscore

I am using double underscore to filter a model or get values from it in Django like this:

```
# filtering model
furthers = myModel.objects.filter(foreignKeyField__furtherField=value)

# getting values
furtherField = myModel.objects.get(id=10).values("foreignKeyField__furtherField")
```

But when I try to use update() method with double underscore like this:

```
myModel.objects.filter(id=10).update("foreignKeyField__furtherField")
```

I get an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: myModel has no field named 'foreignKeyField__furtherField'
```

I looked up documentations about this but there is neither usage example of double underscore for update() method nor a word I cant use it like this way. So could we say update() method cannot be used like this?

Comment: From the docs `The update() method is applied instantly, and the only restriction on the QuerySet that is updated is that it can only update columns in the model’s main table, not on related models.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update this way but you can update it other way round

You should use reverse foreign key relationship like this

```
ForeignModel.objects.filter(mymodel_set__id=10).update(foreign_key_field=some_value)
```

Comment: This method gave me an idea to gather info about related model's update that I am going to try in my project. Every model needs to be updated on by own, got it again :)